# Can I apply for a Mexican visa from the UAE when I'm not a citizen of either country?

Tags: visas, mexico

I want to apply for a Mexican visa from within the United Arab Emirates, but I am not a UAE citizen and I don't want to return to my home country to apply for one. I am in Dubai.

Is it possible for me to apply for a Mexican visa from within the UAE?

Comment: What country are you a citizen of?

Comment: Also, the correct answer might prefer you travel the hour to Abu Dhabi; is this possible within your timeframe & finances?  The bus from Dubai to Abu Dhabi is about 25 dirhams during the week.

Comment: It is normal to get a visa in one's country of residence.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, from [Secretaría de Relaciones Exteriores](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/emiratosarabesunidos/index.php/2016-05-07-05-34-59/2016-05-07-10-39-06):

> VISA Application Process
>
> The Embassy of Mexico in United Arab Emirates has the honor to inform
>   recent developments in the Mexican immigration law.
>
> According to the new regulations all passport holders, regardless of
>   their nationalities and their country of residence, having a valid
>   visa to enter the United States of America will be able to enter the
>   Mexican territory without the need to apply for a Mexican visa as of
>   May 1st, 2010.
>
> REQUIREMENTS:
>
> 1.- Visa application dully filled with capital letters.
>
> 2.- Valid passport with at least two blank pages. Validity of at least six months prior expiry.
>
> 3.- Passport photocopies of the first 3 pages and all valid visas.
>
> 4.- Two passport sized pictures of applicant on a white background (Uncovered head).
>
> 5.- Proof of economic solvency:
>
> a) Letter from applicant’s employer stating salary, length of
>   employment and position .
>
> b) Statements of the applicant’s bank account of the last 3 months and
>   photocopies.
>
> c) International credit card (with an upper limit higher than one
>   thousand USD) and photocopy.
>
> d) Return plane ticket and photocopy
>
> If traveling with family members, depending on the kind of relation,
>   birth certificate &/or marriage certificate and photocopy of each
>   document.
>
> - If in Arabic, must be translated into Spanish
>
> 6.- Consular fee:
>
> Dirhams only (Bring the exact amount)
>
> For Tourist Visa: 133 AED (cash only)
>
> For FM3 (migratory form usually used for business trips): 500 AED
>   (cash only)
>
> 7.- The applicant has to be resident in the United Arab Emirates
>
> Should you need further clarification, please do not hesitate to
>   contact us.
>
> Once you gather the documents required, you can come to the Embassy
>   from Sunday to Thursday from 8:00 AM to 1:00 PM. (Required
>   appointment).
>
> Detalles
>       Última actualización: 18 Mayo 2016

The address is: Villa 1, Sector 23, Plot. 7 A, Bain Al Jessrain, Dubai, Abu Dhabi, P.O. Box: 108543, United Arab Emirates

Other contact details:

Phone: +97-12-5580088
Fax: +97-12-5580077
Email: embamex@eim.ae
Website URL: http://embamex.sre.gob.mx/emiratosarabesunidos

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can find the Mexican embassy in UAE, you will be able to apply for a visa. You will have to show that you are legally allowed in UAE then you shouldn't have a problem.